# Hazelcast embedded cache printing too many logs( Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#d3566be0> j.l.IllegalArgumentException...)

Tags: spring, kubernetes, caching, openshift, hazelcast

I have a spring boot 2.5 application with spring spring security 5 where I am using embedded hazelcast cache to back spring sessions. This application is deployed on openshift with two pods where same application is running, hence I have used hazelcast kubernetes plugin for service discovery. Everything is working as expected. However, I can see application logs are flooded with below log lines.
**Any suggestion what is wrong with the hazelcast configuration ? Why so many log lines are generated ?**

**Generated logs**

10.1.8.58 is IP address of second pod which joined cluster later and logs are printed in this pod only.

```
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:00:43.732+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"INFO","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Removing null, since it thinks it's already split from this cluster and looking to merge."}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:00:43.733+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"ERROR","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#d3566be0> j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.checkTarget(OutboundResponseHandler.java:226)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendNormalResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:125)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:88)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:475)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:282)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:469)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat c.h.i.u.e.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:00:43.734+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"WARN","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] While sending op error... op: com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp{serviceName='hz:core:clusterService', identityHash=1017993990, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=324850, invocationTime=1622710843731 (2021-06-03 19:00:43.731), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.tenantcontrol.NoopTenantControl@0}, error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#dbcc9949> j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701, response: ErrorResponse{callId=324850, urgent=true, cause=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701}\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.send(OutboundResponseHandler.java:113)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:96)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:475)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponseAfterOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:425)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.handleOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:419)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:253)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:469)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat c.h.i.u.e.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:00:43.786+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"INFO","thread":"hz.silly_gates.InvocationMonitorThread","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Invocations:2 timeouts:1 backup-timeouts:0"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:02:43.732+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"INFO","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Removing null, since it thinks it's already split from this cluster and looking to merge."}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:02:43.733+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"ERROR","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#d3566be0> j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.checkTarget(OutboundResponseHandler.java:226)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendNormalResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:125)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:88)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:475)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:282)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:469)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat c.h.i.u.e.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:02:43.734+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"WARN","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] While sending op error... op: com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp{serviceName='hz:core:clusterService', identityHash=1466719815, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=324859, invocationTime=1622710963731 (2021-06-03 19:02:43.731), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.tenantcontrol.NoopTenantControl@0}, error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#dbcc9949> j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701, response: ErrorResponse{callId=324859, urgent=true, cause=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701}\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.send(OutboundResponseHandler.java:113)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:96)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:475)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponseAfterOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:425)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.handleOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:419)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:253)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:469)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat c.h.i.u.e.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:02:43.786+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"INFO","thread":"hz.silly_gates.InvocationMonitorThread","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Invocations:2 timeouts:1 backup-timeouts:0"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:04:43.732+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"INFO","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Removing null, since it thinks it's already split from this cluster and looking to merge."}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:04:43.733+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"ERROR","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#d3566be0> j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.checkTarget(OutboundResponseHandler.java:226)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendNormalResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:125)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:88)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:475)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:282)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:469)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat c.h.i.u.e.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:04:43.733+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"WARN","thread":"hz.silly_gates.priority-generic-operation.thread-0","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] While sending op error... op: com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp{serviceName='hz:core:clusterService', identityHash=244619937, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=324868, invocationTime=1622711083731 (2021-06-03 19:04:43.731), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.tenantcontrol.NoopTenantControl@0}, error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701","stack_trace":"<#dbcc9949> j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701, response: ErrorResponse{callId=324868, urgent=true, cause=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [10.1.8.58]:5701}\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.send(OutboundResponseHandler.java:113)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:96)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:475)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponseAfterOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:425)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.handleOperationError(OperationRunnerImpl.java:419)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:253)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:469)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:197)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)\n\tat c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)\n\tat c.h.i.u.e.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-06-03T19:04:43.786+10:00","app":"my-protected-application","logLevel":"INFO","thread":"hz.silly_gates.InvocationMonitorThread","eventSource":"com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor","message":"[10.1.8.58]:5701 [spring-session-cluster] [4.2] Invocations:2 timeouts:1 backup-timeouts:0"}
```

Maven dependencies included are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-hazelcast</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-kubernetes</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Kubernetes service discovery is configured as below :

```
var joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true)
                .setProperty("service-dns", "dns-name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you get `SplitBrainMergeValidationOp` means that the Hazelcast cluster might have been started in the split-brain and later tries to merge into one cluster. Could you check if you follow all the [Hazelcast Kubernetes recommendations](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#requirements-and-recommendations)?

Especially, check if you use StatefulSet (not Deployment). In the case of DNS Lookup discovery, using Deployment may cause Hazelcast to start in the split-brain mode.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed problem is same as suggested we have used Deployment with DNS Lookup discovery. However, how to resolve this issue if we want to use Deployment with DNS loopup discovery? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try increasing the value of the `service-dns-timeout` parameter.